# Celery worker: periodic local background task

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, celery, background-process

Is there any Celery functionality or preferred way of executing periodic background tasks locally when using a single worker?  Sort of like a background thread, but scheduled and handled by Celery?

`celery.beat` doesn't seem suitable as it appears to be simply tied to a consumer (so could run on any server) - that's the type of scheduling I was after, but just a task that is always run locally on each server running this worker (the task does some cleanup and stats relating to the main task the worker handles).

I may be going about this the wrong way, but I'm confined to implementing this within a celery worker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [a custom remote control command](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#writing-your-own-remote-control-commands) and use [the broadcast function](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#the-broadcast-function) on a cron to run cleanup or whatever else might be required.

Comment: Hmm yes I can see that workflow possibly working, though feels like it's from the wrong end (would rather Celery initiate).  We've also had issues with reliability with broadcasts in the past.

Answer (score 0):

One possible method I thought of, though not ideal, is to patch the `celery.worker.heartbeat Heart()` class.

Since we already use heartbeats, the class allows for a simple modification to its `start()` method (add another `self.timer.call_repeatedly()` entry), or an additional  `self.eventer.on_enabled.add()` `__init__` entry which references a new method that also uses `self.timer.call_repeatedly()` to perform a periodic task.